# Prove $\frac{3\sqrt{xyz}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}} \leq \frac{2}{3} \left(\frac{xy}{x+y}+\frac{yz}{y+z}+\frac{zx}{z+x} \right)$ for $x,y,z \geq 0$

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, means

**This inequality is wrong - see the accepted answer** (it appears there is no general inequality for these two expressions).

On the left we have harmonic mean of pairwise geometric means, which obeys:

$$\sqrt[3]{xyz} \geq  \color{blue}{ \frac{3\sqrt{xyz}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}}} \geq 2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}} \geq  \frac{3xyz}{xy+yz+zx}$$

On the right we have arithmetic means of pairwise harmonic means, obeying the same inequality (**the first inequality here may not be true as well, waiting for proof in another question**):

$$\sqrt[3]{xyz} \geq  \color{blue}{ \frac{2}{3} \left(\frac{xy}{x+y}+\frac{yz}{y+z}+\frac{zx}{z+x} \right)} \geq 2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}} \geq  \frac{3xyz}{xy+yz+zx}$$

According to Wolfram Alpha the following is true:

> $$\frac{3\sqrt{xyz}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}} \leq \frac{2}{3} \left(\frac{xy}{x+y}+\frac{yz}{y+z}+\frac{zx}{z+x} \right)$$

But I have not been able to prove it so far.

---

It may help to transform the RHS in the following way:

$$\frac{2}{3} \left(\frac{xy}{x+y}+\frac{yz}{y+z}+\frac{zx}{z+x} \right)=\frac{2}{3} \frac{xyz(x+y+z)+(xy+yz+zx)^2}{(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)-xyz}$$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original question is an unmotivated inequality that is not correct.  In this case I think there is little long-term benefit to archiving it on this site, because there is no reason to expect anyone else to look for this particular inequality.

Comment: @CarlMummert, very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inequality is wrong! For $y=z=1$ and $x\rightarrow+\infty$ we obtain:

$3\leq\frac{2}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+1\right)$, which is wrong.

Comment: You are right. I did not expect this to happen. So far every inequality made of mean values worked

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Hint:

$\frac{3\sqrt{xyz}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}}\left(\frac{xy}{x+y}+\frac{yz}{y+z}+\frac{zx}{z+x} \right)^{-1} \leq \frac{2}{3} $

$\to 2.\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right) \leq \frac{2}{3}.\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}}{3\sqrt{xyz}}=\frac{2}{9}.\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{yz}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{xz}} \right) $

Comment: How did you get from $$\left(\frac{xy}{x+y}+\frac{yz}{y+z}+\frac{zx}{z+x} \right)^{-1}$$ to $$2 \left( \frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{y}+ \frac{1}{z} \right)$$?

Comment: yes you right ı did mistake